# Is it illegal to edit save files

Tags: android

I have been thinking to make a app, which will replace exisiting saved data of **subway surfer game** with a another saved data. Basically i have scored lot of points and earned lot of coins in the game. I will copy my save data to the users saved data. So the user will get all coins, highscore and unlocks i have made.

I just want to know is this illegal to make app like this ?

Comment: Yeah. It's `Illegal` to do these. Once your app found to be intruding data in some another app then. Your `android developer account` will be `suspended` and `applications` uploaded from your account is removed from `Google Play Store`. Replacing the data in some another app is not really easy to get through. Intruding to some application data needs `sharedUserId and process` permission which can be available if and only if application is signed by the same developer.

Comment: I mean only modifying the files inside android/data/ folder

Comment: you can modify `android/data/game/` but not through `Google Play Store- Your Application`. Cause getting access to internal storage area of another application is totally against `Android Agreement`.

Comment: really thanks for your advice Following rules is my priority.